# Parse large (.5Gb) pcap file in python

Tags: python, list, file, pcap

I have a large pcap file that I am parsing using python code below. The code works but there is a problem with it. When I parse the pcap file as one can see in the code below, I store the values in another file called filename

```
pkts=rdpcap("MyFile.pcap")
def parsePcap():
    IPList = []
    for pkt in pkts:
        if IP in pkt:
            ip_src=pkt[IP].src
            ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
            ip_proto=pkt[IP].proto
       IPList.append((ip_src,ip_dst,ip_proto))
    return IPList


#parseOutput = parsePcap()

f = open('filename', 'w')
f.write(' '.join(map(str, parsePcap()))) 
f.close()
```

The problem comes when I retrieve the values from "filename". I get the following output (exact sample below). But it isn't what it looks like.

```
('121.14.142.72',
'0.32.59.21',
6,
)
('123.152.135.217',
'0.3.17.121',
17,
)
('71.229.65.158',
'0.48.101.12',
17,
)
```

When I run the following code -

```
uniqueNodePairs=[]

myArr = map(str, open("filename").readline().strip().split())

for i in myArr:
    print i
    uniqueNodePairs.append((i[0],i[1]))# pairs of src., dst

for i in  uniqueNodePairs:
    print i
```

I get the following -

```
('(', "'")
("'", '0')
('6', ')')
('(', "'")
("'", '0')
('1', '7')
('(', "'")
("'", '0')
```

which means the values are not getting stored as strings but individual characters. This is not what I want. I want something like this as the output

```
('121.14.142.72','0.32.59.21'),
('123.152.135.217','0.3.17.121'),...
```

Comment: Does the output file need to be formatted that way?

Comment: Are you inserting the newlines in the file contents you're showing? I don't see any code that would be producing them, and your processing code doesn't make sense if there are multiple lines (you only read one). The comma before the closing parentheses also seems to be bogus (the code won't produce it, and your processing function doesn't seem to see it).

Comment: @ChristianTernus - I will be using the output as an input for the rest of the program, e.g. connections between IP addresses etc.., so yes I will be needing full IP addresses as output

Comment: @Blckknght - I'm not inserting any newlines on purpose, not even for presentation sake. What I've copy-pasted here is exactly how the output comes up.

Comment: But do you really need the quote marks around each IP address? It seems to me that it would be simpler to do `f.write('\n'.join(' '.join([str(item) for item in triple]) for triple in parsePcap()))`

Comment: Let me clarify. Is the block with each IP and protocol on a separate line the contents of your `"filename"` file? Or is that the output of the first loop in your second block of code?

Comment: Because that should give you output lines like `192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 6`, which will be MUCH easier for you to parse later.

Comment: @rmunn - I hadn't thought of this before. No I do not have specific reason to use quotes. This is how I saw the output so far and I just went with it, which is not a very smart explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's *part* of your problem, at least:

```
myArr = map(str, open("filename").readline().strip().split())
```

When you're calling `readline()` here, you're only reading a single line.

To fix *that particular line* you probably want:

```
map(lambda x: str(x.strip().split()), open("filename").readlines())
```

but that won't solve your whole issue. You want to be producing files that look something like this:

```
('121.14.142.72','0.32.59.21',6)
('123.152.135.217','0.3.17.121',17)
```

in order to read them in properly that way.

Why not try something like this?

```
with open("filename", 'w') as f:
    for i in parsePcap():
        f.write("('%s','%s',%d)\n" % i)
```

But if you just want to store the array temporarily to pass it between programs, I'd recommend not writing your own parsing code. Try using the `pickle` or `json` modules to store your data in a more easily-readable format.

Comment: `split` splits on whitespace, never on characters. The issue the questioner is getting is that `i` in his loop is a string, not a tuple of strings.

Comment: I'd even suggest producing lines that look like `121.14.142.72 0.32.59.21 6`, for ease of future parsing. Of course, `pickle` or `json` is even better, as you suggest.

Comment: All thanks! I'll experiment with the code keeping your comments in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider. Your input file is 5Gb, so you should perhaps not be returning a list from your parsePcap() function. Since all you're doing with that list is iterating over it anyway, it's better to turn your function into a generator by using the `yield` keyword. Here's your original function:

```
def parsePcap():
    IPList = []
    for pkt in pkts:
        if IP in pkt:
            ip_src=pkt[IP].src
            ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
            ip_proto=pkt[IP].proto
        IPList.append((ip_src,ip_dst,ip_proto))
    return IPList
```

And here's what it looks like as a generator:

```
def parsePcap():
    for pkt in pkts:
        if IP in pkt:
            ip_src=pkt[IP].src
            ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
            ip_proto=pkt[IP].proto
        yield (ip_src,ip_dst,ip_proto)
```

That way, you won't ever store the entire list in memory: as each src,dst,proto triple is ready, it gets returned from the function, written out to your output file, and then disposed of from memory.

By using generators instead of building up a list and returning it, you'll allow yourself to process much larger files. 5Gb is less than the amount of RAM on most modern systems, so that input file isn't a real problem — but if you had a 500Gb file to process, you'd find the generator version MUCH faster than the build-a-list-and-return-it version, which would be constantly hitting the swap file.

Comment: I think the title is saying a ".5Gb" or 500 MB file. That's even further from most system memory limits. Your point is a good one though, processing item by item is usually a better design!

Comment: @Blckknght - You're right; I missed that period. It's a bit of a moot point, since `rdpcap()` is constructing and returning a list rather than acting as a generator (I checked scapy's source, though I'm not 100% sure that what I saw was the latest version). So there's at least one step (outside of the OP's control) that would be slow on a huge file. Still, good design is always good to think about.

Comment: @rmunn - Glad you noticed and suggested yield as an option. i was about to ask RAM/time related issues as my followup question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about the output you report getting, as I don't think it's possible (the newlines and some of the trailing commas seem to come from nowhere). However, I think I understand what's going wrong in your code.

If I understand correctly, you need to write out the `(source, destination, protocol)` three-tuples to a file, then later read them back in and print out just the source and destination IP addresses (or do something with them, anyway).

The issue you're having is that you're calling `str` on the tuples themselves, which means you're get output that confuses your later processing code. Specifically, the `map` call you're making in your `write` is not appropriate.

You probably want `" ".join(",".join(map(str, tup)) for tup in parsePcap()`. This will format the tuples like `121.14.142.72,0.32.59.21,6` (without the parenthes and quotation marks). Further, it will separate the multiple tuples by spaces, so the three tuples in your example output would be written to your file as:

```
121.14.142.72,0.32.59.21,6 123.152.135.217,0.3.17.121,17 71.229.65.158,0.48.101.12,17
```

Your parsing code will need a small update too. Currently you're splitting on whitespace, but then processing the results as if you will get the tuples back. You need to split again (on the commas), before you'll be able to handle the separate items:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    myArr = [i.split(',') for i in f.readline().split()]
```

I've changed up quite a few things here. The `with` statement opens the file and makes sure it gets closed again afterwards. The list is created with a list comprehension, which iterates over the space-separated substrings read from the file and splits each one so that you get back almost the same thing that was returned by `parsePcap` in the first script (not quite, the inner values are lists rather than tuples and the protocol is a string rather than an int).

The `strip` and `map(str, ...)` calls you were doing were completely unnecessary (`split` with no arguments ignores leading and trailing whitespace, and all the values you read from the file are strings already).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It makes a lot of sense about the mistakes I've made plus how I can improve. I have no explanation to offer on why the output looks the way it does except that it is what I've shared. I'm trying the alternate code that you and rmunn have suggested as of now.